# Rails allow user to configure ActionMailer at runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I want to create a Rails application where on first request the user is directed to a setup configuration wizard. In this wizard they will need to configure their email settings for ActionMailer to use, ie. SMTP server settings/credentials.

How can I programatically update the configuration entries for ActionMailer (I assume Application.rb will need to be updated)?

How can I make ActionMailer reload these updated configuration settings? I noticed that a lot of these settings are loaded on application start/initialization and I don't want to restart the Rails application for these changes to take effect.

Comment: It may not have been obvious, these SMTP settings given by the user should then used as the global SMTP settings across the application. The user is being allowed to set a site wide configuration.

Answer (score 7):

Just store settings into session and do this inside before filter for your AC:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    before_filter :set_mailer_settings

    private

      def set_mailer_settings

        ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
          :address  => session[:smtp_address],
          :port  => session[:smtp_port],
          :domain => session[:smtp_domain],
          :authentication => session[:smtp_authentication],
          :user_name => session[:smtp_user_name],
          :password => session[:smtp_password]
        }

      end

end
```

Comment: Wouldn't I want to store it somewhere more permanent than the session? Isn't this hugely inefficient as its setting the ActionMailer config on every request on every controller despite the fact I'll probably only be using the ActionMailer from a couple of places, generally invoked from a background process too.

Comment: @KrisG That is common problem - before filter in AC is not a good place for setting the config, but I don't know any other solution for it... You could store settings into database instead of session as well, I've just made a quick sample there.